# Install updates SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, installation, update

I cannot apply installed updates for SharePoint 2016 in any way, the SharePoint products configuration wizard fails:

**The update process failed to start.**

> Type exception thrown Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException.
>   More information about the exception: one or more types could not be
>   loaded. For more information, see the update log.
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: One or more types
>   could not be loaded. For more information, see the update log.
>
> in Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()
>   in Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_Actions() in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_RunnableActions() in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.RunPreUpgraders(Object
>   o, List`1 lstClass) in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o,
>   Boolean bRecurse) in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.BootStrap(Guid sessionId,
>   SPUpgradeOperationFlags flags) in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run()
>   in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2016/04/15/spupgradeexception-error-message-when-you-run-the-sharepoint-products-and-technologies-configuration-wizard-when-you-create-a-new-sharepoint-2016-farm/

Comment: https://blog.devoworx.net/2018/05/21/sharepoint-2016-failed-to-create-the-configuration-database-an-exception-of-type-microsoft-sharepoint-upgrade-spupgradeexception-was-thrown/

Comment: Removed the WCF data Services 5.6 component installed anew, but did not try to install via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The products configuration wizard is a little bit crazy. It often fails in the first run without any good reason.

- Run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. This regularly fails. Directly run the wizard again. No troubleshooting or even a look at the error-log here!
- If update still fails, open SharePoint PowerShell and run `psconfig.exe` with the following parameters:
  `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`
- Again: If the first run fails, run `psconfig.exe`again with the same set of parameters without any troubleshooting.
- If all of this failes, you really need to troubleshoot this issue. But you will get 95% of your issues resolved just with this weird procedure.